# Ionic, I have trouble with my side menu, I need the same one on every pages

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm working on an app using Ionic and I'm a beginner with it, I need to put a side menu ( the same one all the time) on every pages I have.

Can you help me doing this pls ?

Here is my actual code on index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

  <ion-side-menus>
      <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
          <ion-nav-buttons side = "right">
            <button class = "button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right"></button>
          </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view>
        </ion-nav-view>
      </ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="home">
          Acceuil
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close ui-sref ="about">
          A Propos
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>

  <ion-tabs class="tabs-balanced tabs-icon-top">

    <ion-tab  ui-sref ="home" title="Accueil" icon="ion-ios-home"></ion-tab>

    <ion-tab ui-sref ="about" title="Carnet de bal" icon="ion-ios-clock-outline"></ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Settings" icon="ion-ios-gear"></ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The common way to do it, is setting a parent abstract route for the menu and loading all views inside of it as a child view, like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "menu.html"
})
.state('app.home', {
  url: "/home",
  views: {
    'appContent' :{
      templateUrl: "home.html",
      controller : "HomeController"
    }
  }
})
```

On menu.html you need to have a nav-view

```
<ion-nav-view name="appContent"></ion-nav-view>
```

Take a look at this article:

http://mcgivery.com/understanding-ionics-side-menu/

And this code sample

https://codepen.io/calendee/pen/Fuejf/

Comment: Hi, I dont know why but it does not work... 
I added this to my app.js : 
'.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state('app',{
    url:"/app",
    abstract : true,
    templateUrl : "templates/menu.html",
    controller : 'AppCtrl'
  })

.state('app.home',{
    url:"/home",
    views:{
      'menuContent':{
        templateUrl :"templates/home.html",
        controller:'homeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })'

Comment: I probably need to see more of your code. Please edit your answer, it's easier then reading code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This all my code :

the app.js :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
})

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('app',{
    url:"templates/app",
    abstract : true,
    templateUrl : "templates/menu.html"
  })

  $stateProvider.state('home',{
    url:'/home',
    templateUrl :'templates/home.html'
  })

  $stateProvider.state('about',{
    url:'/about',
    templateUrl : 'templates/about.html'
  })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')

});
```

the index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  <!--Onglets du bas en liens avec les pages-->

  <ion-tabs class="tabs-balanced tabs-icon-top">

    <ion-tab  ui-sref ="home" title="Accueil" icon="ion-ios-home"></ion-tab>

    <ion-tab ui-sref ="about" title="Carnet de bal" icon="ion-ios-clock-outline"></ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Settings" icon="ion-ios-gear"></ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>

  </body>
</html>
```

home.html :

```
<ion-view view-title="Accueil">

    <ion-content scroll="false">

        <div class="centerButton">
            <div class="button-bar">
                <a ui-sref="about" class ="button"><img src="img/map.png" width="120"><p>Plan</p></a>
                <a ui-sref="about" class ="button"><img src="img/catalogue.png" width="120"><p>Catalogue</p></a>
                <a ui-sref="about" class ="button"><img src="img/information.png" width="120"><p>Info pratiques</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="button-bar">
                <a ui-sref="about" class ="button"><img src="img/ios7-bookmarks.png" width="120"><p>Les Chapitres</p></a>
                <a ui-sref="about" class ="button"><img src="img/qrcode.png" width="120"><p>Flash code</p></a>
                <a ui-sref="about" class ="button"><img src="img/map.png" width="120"><p>Archives audiovisuel</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And menu.html :

```
<ion-nav-view name="appContent">
  <ion-side-menus>
      <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
          <ion-nav-buttons side = "right">
            <button class = "button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right"></button>
          </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view>
        </ion-nav-view>
      </ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="home">
          Acceuil
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close ui-sref ="about">
          A Propos
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>
</ion-nav-view>
```